# Reversing a number in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm currently working on a introductory class to Python and this is one of the labs I'm working on.

Here is the lab prompt:

Write a program that takes in a positive integer as input, and outputs a string of 1's and 0's representing the
integer in reverse binary. For integer x, the algorithm is:

As long as x is greater than 0
Output x modulo 2 (remainder is either 0 or 1)
Assign x with x divided by 2

Note: The algorithm above outputs 0's and 1's in reverse order.

Ex: if input is 6 the output is 011

How would you solve this?

```
number = int(input('Enter your number\n'))
number_list = []

while number != 0:
    number = number // 2
    number_list.append((number % 2))
    number_list.reverse()
    print(number_list)
```

I tried converting the number into a string but was not successful. This is my best attempt at it.

Comment: first you should convert every item on list to string and later join all string to one string- like `"".join( str(item) for item in number_list )`

Comment: Nothing needs reversed. For 6, 3, 1 modulo 2 yields 011, as expected

Comment: as for me you have to mistakes. First: you should first use modulo `%` and later assign new value to `number = ...`. Second: you don't need `reverse()` because `append()` already creates reversed list. You would need `reverse()` after `while`-loop if you would use `insert(0, ...)` instead of `append()`

Comment: I see also problem with input value `0` because it will create empty list :)

Comment: to reduce code which converts result to string you could use `str()` directly in `append()` - like `.append( str(number % 2) )` - and later you willl need only `join` elements - like `print( "".join(number_list) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing the remainder in the list, you are already reversing the list. No need to reverse it again. And again . . .

You just need to store the remainder, *then* divide by two.

Then print the answer outside the loop:

```
number = int(input('Enter your number:'))
number_list = []

while number != 0:
    number_list.append(number % 2)
    number = number // 2

print(number_list)
```

Example output:

```
Enter your number:12
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! You just taught me more than my professor! I appreciate it.

Comment: still problem makes input `0` because it gives empty list. It may need to add some `if/else` to add `0` to list.

Comment: or it would need to use `while True` and check `number != 0` (and use `break`) after calculations (similar to `do ... until` in other languages). This way it will calculations (and use `append()`) even for input value `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `divmod` for this. `divmod` will give you the results of floor division and modulo, in one line.

```
x   = int(input('Enter your number: '))
out = []

# As long as x is greater than 0
while x:
    # Assign x with x divided by 2
    x, xm2 = divmod(x, 2)
    # Output x modulo 2
    out.append(xm2)
    
print(out)
```